# How to declare Model in flutter? It Error Task .fromJson and List<>Data. Using Laravel Api

Tags: flutter

[image]

How to declare Model in flutter? It Error Task .fromJson and List<>Data. Using Laravel Api

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
class Task {
  String links;
  
  Task(this.links);

  Task.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    this.links = json["Links"] != null? do stuff : do stuff; 
  }
}
```

Reference : https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json

Comment: List<Links> links; How to declare in Task.fromJson ?